# Posts not arranged in perfectly masonry order in tumblr theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, tumblr, jquery-masonry, masonry

My Tumblr theme was working perfectly before, but after the tumblr enforcing us to change URLs from http to https, so I uploaded the same masonry.js file in theme assets. And my javascript file got changed from

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://.../masonry.js"></script>
```

to

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://.../masonry.js"></script>
```

But now the posts are not arranging perfectly as before. I am attaching the HTML, CSS and javascript code of the theme. Please help. Thank you in advance.

### CSS

```css
#content {
    {block:IndexPage}
    width:66%;
    {/block:IndexPage}
    
     {block:PermalinkPage}
    width: 55%;
    {/block:PermalinkPage}
    top:170px;
    
    {block:IndexPage}
    left: 1%;
    {/block:IndexPage}
    {block:PermalinkPage}
    left: 10%;
    {/block:PermalinkPage}
    
    float: left; 
    position: absolute;
}

.entry {
    float:center;
    {block:indexpage}
    width: 43%;
    overflow:hidden;
    {/block:indexpage}
    margin: 2%; 
    {block:permalinkpage}
    width: 500px;
    {/block:permalinkpage}
    padding: 10px;
    background: {color:box};
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    z-index:4;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
       -moz-border-radius:3px;
       border-radius:3px;
} 
.entry img {
    display: block;
    width:auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

### HTML

```html
<div class="autopagerize_page_element">
{block:Posts}
<div class="entry">
...POSTS...
...POSTS...
...POSTS...
</div>
{/block:Posts}
</div>
```

### JAVASCRIPT

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.tumblr.com/82upcij/kv2pl8cna/masonry1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function () {
$(".autopagerize_page_element").masonry({ itemSelector: ".entry" });
$('.masonryWrap').infinitescroll({
navSelector    : '#pagination',  
nextSelector   : '#pagination a#nextPage',
itemSelector : ".entry, .clear",
bufferPx : 40,
loadingImg : "",
loadingText : "Loading",
},
function() { $('#content').masonry({ appendedContent: $(this) }); }
);
});
</script>
```

Comment: You question is not very clear. What is the JavaScript change (first paragraph) for example?

Comment: Sorry, I changed it now. Please look in to it. Please look at the arrangement of posts in my blog http://funny-adults.com and you will understand

Comment: I found the solution to my problem. It was because jquery 3.3.1 doesn't support `$(window).load(function(){...});` So I replaced it with `$(window).on('load', function(){ ...});` And now it's working perfectly. Thank you for trying.